# change language on rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have a web with no language configuration, because I'm only using one language.

I installed rails_admin gem, and I want it on the language of the rest of the web instead of english. But I'm a newbie in the rails language configurations and I don't understand them very well yet.

I  added a rails_admin.ca.yml file under the folder "config/locales" in my rails project, and `config.i18n.default_locale = :ca`, but it is not working.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Translations

Can anybody help me?

PD: I installed also the gem 'rails_admin-i18n' but still not working

Comment: have you restarted your server since you installed the gems and changed the configuration?

Comment: yes, I restarted the server and that was not the problem.

I just solved it, I removed "config.i18n.default_locale = :ca" from application.rb and placed it inside the "Rails.application.configure do" of development.rb and now it's working. I placed it inside production.rb too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it.

I removed `config.i18n.default_locale = :ca` from `config/application.rb` and placed it inside the `Rails.application.configure do` of `config/environments/development.rb` and now it's working.

I placed it inside production.rb and test.rb too.